# Want to create new sheets that copy a template in a specific order based on a list of names on a sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I wanted to create new sheets based on a list and have all those new sheets copy a template on a currently existing sheet.
I've tried looking for examples but all the ones i find only create a list of sheets, or just copy the template. I know im close but I can't seem to get this to work.

This is what i have so far, and it works, but when the sheets are created they show up as client3, client2, client1. I want it to show up in the reverse order. I know i need to change the copy after statement but every time I try I get an error. Any help would be appreciated
Sheets names i have are Clients and Scan

```
Option Explicit
Sub NewSheets()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Scan")
Set sh = Sheets("Clients")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Scan")
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("Scan").Copy After:=sh2
        ActiveSheet.Name = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub NewSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Scan")
Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Sheets("Clients")
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 2 To sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Scan").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Yep that works, At first I was getting some errors, but that was because Id renamed the sheets and moved the list to a different column before i realized you'd have had no way of knowing that before you replied :p.